Streamlit throwing TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation why using html from Pgwalker.walk
I have a dataframe named data and I want to visualize it using:
        walker = pyg.walk(data, return_html=True)
        st.components.v1.html(walker, width=1100, height=800) 

pyg is pygwalker and st is import streamlit as st
But I get:
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\trist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\exec_code.py", line 75, in exec_func_with_error_handling
    result = func()
             ^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\trist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 574, in code_to_exec
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Desktop\GitHub\nfl-data-app\nfl_data.py", line 125, in <module>
    st.components.v1.html(walker, width=1100, height=800)    #Adjust width and height as needed
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\trist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\metrics_util.py", line 408, in wrapped_func
    result = non_optional_func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\trist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\iframe.py", line 129, in _html
    marshall(
File "C:\Users\trist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\iframe.py", line 180, in marshall
    proto.srcdoc = srcdoc

^^^^^^^^^^^^

I was expecting my streamlit app to display the dashboard. It works otherwise.

Not quite sure what's the version of pygwalker and streamlit you are using. But I recommend first upgrade your pygwalker to latest version, then follow the offical pygwalker streamlit api example of the latest version.

Upgrade pygwalker

pip install pygwalker --upgrade


PyGWalker + Streamlit Latest API

from pygwalker.api.streamlit import StreamlitRenderer
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
 
# Adjust the width of the Streamlit page
st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Use Pygwalker In Streamlit",
    layout="wide"
)
# Import your data
# df = <your dataframe>
 
pyg_app = StreamlitRenderer(df)
 
pyg_app.explorer()

